# how can I enforce TextView to process its text and render it

Tags: c#, gtk

I am using GTK and when I insert the text into TextView, it seems to process it in a background thread.

1. I insert a text on 1 line
2. I do some other stuff, but in this very moment the text is not yet even rendered there
3. I use ScrollToIter() so that it scroll to bottom - BUT because the text isn't rendered yet, there is no end to scroll to, so nothing really happen

if I insert the scroll to end into some timer, it works - but it's pretty slow and weird. (the text is first drawn and then after it's done it jump to bottom, for long text it jumps several times because drawing takes a long time).

Also everytime when I change the Buffer.Text the control redraw all lines (appending line by line in a loop, which is also looking very annoying).

What I need to do, is:

1. Change TextView.Buffer.Text to different string
2. Enforce TextView to process all text and redraw immediately
3. Scroll to bottom

In example:

Let's imagine you want to create a text editor which is supposed to open large text file (100 000 lines) and immediately after it open the file, it scroll to its bottom. So ideally, you open the file and first what you see is the bottom of it. This is what happens in many text editors. I would like to implement this behaviour with this gtk thing.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

that's not how event-driven programming in a main loop based toolkit works. the fundamental tenet of event-driven programming with toolkits using a main loop, like GTK+, is: you **never** block the main loop.

GTK+ does not use separate threads to render and layout: every blocking operation you perform will prevent other operations from running, which include drawing, event handling, and your own code.

you should scroll to the bottom of the TextView once the buffer has been updated, using the notification signals that TextBuffer provides; you should also **never** insert (long) text in a tight loop: if you want to insert text line by line, or more likely chunk by chunk, you should subdivide the job into smaller pieces, and use idle callbacks or timeout callbacks, which will be executed within the main loop.

Comment: ok I am fine with events, but then the question is, what the event name is for control finish its drawing? If I knew it I could just run scroll to end on that signal (btw I am not inserting a long text in a loop - I am inserting long text in 1 line of code (textview.Buffer.Text = longtext) it just appears to me like if it was inserted in a loop given the way how it's rendered

Comment: by the way - are you sure there is no way to "speed up" the text rendering? I would like to know how many text editors written in GTK handle opening of large text files, because I never see this what I see in my own application anywhere...